How to ensure uniqueness of rule ids of declarativeNetRequest for 2+ rules targeted towards a single tab(tabId). in chrome extension manifest V3
I want to ensure uniqueness of IDs of 2(or more) declarativeNetRequest rules applied on a single tab.
These  rules can be applied in multiple  tabs.(based on certain dynamic logic)
So rule  they cannot be applied using condition:tabIds as each rule's action varies.
Now I have to use integer for this .
What can be done to ensure unique ids. Since its not clear from the docs that what logic chrome uses to assign tabsIds. So cannot do something like
Rule 1 - tabId
Rule 2 -  tabId *1000 (ids may collide).
Is there a fool proof logic . Esentially I want to have non-persistent tab scoped rules.
Note : I don't care about deleting these rules as they are supposed to remain as long as the tab is "alive".
inside chrome.tabs.onUpdated we are doing certain calculations based on the URLs of the tabs opened and deciding rules to apply to certain tabs
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addEvenetListener(function(tabId,details)
{
        const val = //some logic that uses currently opened tabs info and does some calculations
        const dynamicallyCreatedRules ={
                id: tabID,
                priority: 1,
                condition: {
                    tabIds: [tabID],
                    requestDomains:[...domains1]
            },
                action: {
                    type: "modifyHeaders",
                    responseHeaders: [
                        { header: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", operation: "set", value: dynamicOriginValue(val) }, 
                    ]
                }
            },{
                id: tabID*10000000,//might conflict with other rules
                priority: 1,
                condition: {
                    tabIds: [tabID],
                    requestDomains:[...domains2]
                },
                action: {
                    type: "modifyHeaders",
                    responseHeaders: [
                        { header: "something", operation: "set", value: dynamicLogic(val)},
                    ]
                }
            },
        
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(dynamicallyCreatedRules)
}

I was thinking of having a rule counter for the Id c=0 and everytime I add a rule I just do c++. But what if a chrome tab ID has the same value as the counter value.

You can store a counter in chrome.storage.session and just increase it by 1 each time.
